# I want to Retrive Downtree of my current Tree

Tags: php, mysql

I have the below tree with present data. I want tree below 103 only.

```
+----------------+----------------+
| child          | parent         |
+----------------+----------------+
| 216            |            103 |
| 217            |            216 |
| 88             |            216 |
| 102            |           NULL |
| 103            |            102 |
| 104            |            102 |
+----------------+----------------+
```

the output should be a below format

```
           102
          /   \ 
        103    104
        /
      216
     /  \
   217   218
```

from this

```
        103 
        /
      216
     /  \
   217   218
```

I need this in Mysql

I tried to get 103 child, then I get 216. again I tried child of 216. and so on in my MYSQL until end. How I get, the tree End?

Comment: Show your current sql query

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: select ref from chain_testing where per='103' -- it gives 216
select ref from chain_testing where per='216' -- it gives 217,218
select ref from chain_testing where per='217' -- it gives null


my question is that, if the tree is very big, this concep is very critical. I am requesting for the better solution in mysql or php

Comment: data array is :

 $sql = "select username,(case when referrel is not null then referrel else null end) as referrel  from login_users where id>=$id order by id";
            echo "$sql";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

            $val = "";
            $data_array = array();

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $data_array[$row['username']] = $row['referrel'];
                }
            } else {
                echo mysqli_error($con);
            }

Comment: function printtree($tree) {
                if (!is_null($tree) && count($tree) > 0) {
                    echo "<ul>";
                    foreach ($tree as $b) {

                        echo "<li><a href='#'>" . $b['name'] . "</a>";
                        printtree($b['children']);
                        echo "</li>";
                    }
                    echo "</ul>";
                }
            }

            printtree(parseTree($data_array));

Comment: the above code displays total tree

Comment: I want to display part of tree

Comment: why don\`t you attach your current code to the question?

Comment: Please kindly tell me, how to attach?

Comment: there is no attach button

Comment: Should the first child in your table be 218 instead of 216?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code which you can alter as per the requirement.

The sample code can be used in Laravel as a Helper function to get all the child nodes.

```
class UserUtility
{

    public static function children_ids($id)
    {
        $children = UserUtility::flat_children($id);

        return !empty($children) ? array_column($children, 'id') : array();
    }


    public static function flat_children($id)
    {
        $children = UserUtility::get_immediate_children($id, $with_trashed, true, $role_id);

        if (!empty($children)) {
            foreach ($children as $child) {

                $container[] = $child;
                $container = UserUtility::flat_children($child['id'], $with_trashed, $container, $role_id);

            }
        }

        return $container;
    }

    public static function get_immediate_children($id)
    {
        $children = User::withoutGlobalScopes()->where('parent_id', $id)->get();  // get the children data from DB
        $children = $as_array && !is_null($children) ? $children->toArray() : array();
        return $children;
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly tell me in pure PHP